# PHP file download including the .php file when only pdf is wanted

Tags: php, pdf, readfile

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['name'];

$path = './curr/'.$file.'.pdf'; // the file made available for download via this PHP file
$mm_type="application/pdf"; // modify accordingly to the file type of $path, but in most cases no need to do so

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file

?>
```

This is a snippet of code in file.php.  I am referring to the file using:

```
<a href="file.php?name=First File">File 1</a>
```

The intent is that on click of the link, `./curr/First File.pdf` should download.  I do get a download, but on inspecting, it's the webpage with the pdf embedded in the file.  Could anyone assist?

Comment: The above code contains everything from the file `file.php` ?

Comment: No.  There is a menu system etc surrounding the download.  As well as login verification.  Should I lose all but the php code?

Comment: @Splatter If you have other HTML on the page, that's going to get output with the downlaod. Your `file.php` should not have _ANY_ markup at all.

Comment: @sirko This worked.  Could you put this as an answer so I can give you a tick for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have just the PDF loaded, the above code is all code to be executed.

Drop all surrounding menus, header or footers. Make sure, that no HTML or any other output besides the PDF from `readfile()` remains, when calling this link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the content type to :

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```

Comment: I get the same.  The .php file with the php gone.  Where this php was is %PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
557 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 1413408/O 559/E 279613/N 9/T 1412909/H [ 483 382]>>
endobj
           
567 0 obj etc etc.

Comment: I hate this so much. As a user, when I click on a PDF link, I want it to open in my browser. I absolutely despise when websites force me to download things that could be viewed in my browser. I can download it if I want to - completely off topic, I know.

Comment: I appreciate this.  But the page has a section to view the pdf on the site too (embedded as an object, I will admit).  This is specifically the download section.